# Rpy2: calling to function conaining dots

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, r-mice

I'm tring to run a R function in Pyton via Jupyter Notebook.
the problem is, that my function name (from mice lib) - containing dot.
the name of the function is `md.pattern`, and this is the code that I'm tring to run:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
mice = importr('mice')
mice.md.pattern(train)
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'mice' has no attribute 'md'
```

I also tried to run:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
mice = importr('mice')

pattern = robjects.r("md.pattern")
mice.pattern(train)
```

and get the same error.

Comment: The second way is ok, but you should use `pattern(train)` and not `mice.pattern(train)`. Ideally, you would use `pattern = robjects.r["md.pattern"]` rather than `pattern = robjects.r("md.pattern")`

Comment: @krassowski, thank you very much! you are the best (-:

Answer (score 5):

Beside the suggested answer in the comments, the doc suggests that the following should work:

```
mice.md_pattern(train)
```

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/introduction.html#importing-packages