# R mice package in Python

Tags: python, r, missing-data, rpy2, r-mice

I'm tring to run R mice package on Python via Jupyter.
I'm struggling with many errors and technical issues.
Let's take the Iris dataset and insert some na's:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

data1.iloc[1,1] = np.nan
data1.iloc[4,4] = np.nan
data1.iloc[149,2] = np.nan
```

**In R**, I would run the folowing script:

```
library(mice)
md.pattern(data1)
imputed_df = mice(data1, m=3)
df = complete(imputed_df,2)
```

and here is the question, **In Python** I'm tring to run the following script:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
Mice = importr('mice')

pattern = robjects.r("md.pattern")
Mice.complete(Mice.mice(pattern(data1), m=3),2)
```

I'm getting two types of errors:

1. on the complete function:

   AttributeError: module 'mice' has no attribute 'complete'
2. on the mice function:

   TypeError: 'NULLType' object is not iterable

**The bottom line is, how do you suggest to run R mice on Python?**

Comment: You may want to accept an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652953/rpy2-calling-to-function-conaining-dots to help others ;)

Comment: Your example is missing `from rpy2 import robjects`; also the module names should be lowercase in Python (so `mice`, not `Mice`)

Comment: One might want to have a look at IterativeImputer from sklearn.impute

Answer (score 2):

1) This is probably because the `complete` function does not come from `mice` library, but from `tidyr`. You can check that in R by simply printing it:

```
print(complete)
```

which shows the namespace it comes from:

```
function (data, ..., fill = list()) 
{
    UseMethod("complete")
}
<bytecode: 0x55bc2e74e1d0>
<environment: namespace:tidyr>
```

I would be curious as to why it is not re-exported in rpy2 the same way as it is in R (an answer from @lgautier would help here).

2) I cannot reproduce; the following works as expected for me:

```
mice = importr('mice')
tidyr = importr('tidyr')

tidyr.complete(mice.mice(pattern(data1), m=3), 2)
```

Comment: @ krassowski, if you replace the `pattern(data1)` to just `data1` - It will not work. any ideas? same error as 2)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

utils = importr('utils')

pandas2ri.activate()

# convert the pandas dataframe to a R dataframe
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
   r_frame = ro.conversion.py2rpy(df)    

# load mice package
mice = importr('mice')

tmp = mice.mice(r_frame, m=5)

# load complete function
complete = ro.r['complete']

df_imputated = complete(tmp, 1)
```